# Add SubItems in TreeView

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm sure this sounds like a n00b question, but how do I add sub items programmically while populating a TreeView list in VB.NET 3.5?  I have the following code, but haven't been able to figure out how to add the sub items for each of the folders/files I'm populating the TreeView with:

```
Private Sub AddToList(ByVal targetDirectory As String, ByVal boolFiles As Boolean, Optional ByVal recur As Boolean = False)

    Dim shortName As String

    TreeView1.Items.Add(targetDirectory)

    //Add subitems under here

    If Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory).Length > 0 Then
        Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
        Dim subdirectory As String

        For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
            shortName = subdirectory.Remove(0, subdirectory.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
            TreeView1.Items.Add(shortName)
            AddToList(subdirectory, False, True)

            If boolFiles = True Then AddToList(subdirectory, boolFiles)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

To clarify, I want my TreeView to look similar to the Windows Explorer look.  I appreciate any and all help!

Thanks in advance!
JFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TreeNode objects, and add sub items to the parent TreeNode, instead of adding everything to the TreeView directly.  Check out [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/RecursivelyloadDirectoryinfointoTreeView.htm).

Comment: Please explain your answer in the question. See this question for why a link to an answer isn't really an answer:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer
Additionally, the linked answer is a C# answer. The question domain is vb.net. This is a self-described noob question, so the answer really should fall within the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Which TreeView is this? In winforms, you simply catch the returned TreeNode from Add, and add more items to the Nodes property:

```
TreeNode parent = treeView.Nodes.Add("parent");
parent.Nodes.Add("child");
```